An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x0) was found in the element content of the document new project
I created a new android project. Completely clean, empty views activity. Without changing anything in the project, when trying to synchronize gradle I get an error during assembly "An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x0) was found in the element content of the document.". I did not change the settings of android studio, but only installed it with standard settings
I tried deleting different xml files, but it was useless

Are you on the latest Android version? Its not the first time I've seen a new project causing an issue, previously I experienced this with a new project creating the project with the incorrect Text import. Anyways, try  with the latest version and see if the resolves the issue. If not, try creating a different template and see if that fixes the issue. If nothing works then create a public git repo so someone can test it out.

@omz1990 , I am using lasted version Android studio.I tried to create projects using other templates, even the compose template. I don't see any point in creating a git repository, the code in the examples is the same for everyone. It seems to me that the problem is in my computer and its crookedly assembled encoding.

I see, interesting. Not sure if you'll get more help here based on that. Out of curiosity Mac or Windows? Might be a silly suggestion, but could spaces/special characters in your folder paths could be a cause for it? Never experienced it though, but could be.
